# невозможно создать абстрактный класс (c# winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Есть библиотека классов включающая абстрактный класс и его наследников.

Есть оконное приложение winform c# к которому эта библиотека подключается.

И проблема в том что при компиляции вылезает вот это: Невозможно создать абстрактный класс. Хотя есть ещё одно приложение ранее написанное и к нему эта библиотека спокойно подключается и все работает...
Версия VS одна и также как и все остальное.

В самой программе использую структуру BindingList которая хранит наследников абстрактного класса и которая связана с dgv для их отображения.

Ссылки проверял, как и место откуда беру dll файл.

Comment: если к консольному приложению подключать, то тоже все работает нормально.

Comment: ошибка компиляции содержит в себе строку, где она возникла. Вот там и ищите свои абстрактные классы.

Comment: Все просто - вы не можете вызвать `new` для абстрактного класса. Можете вызвать только для наследников, вот и вызывайте для наследников.

Comment: Это я понимаю только вот в программе я используя абстрактный класс для полиморфизма и создаю только наследников. И в одном случае как я написал все работает на ура, а в другом появляется это исключение.

Comment: Значит вы попытались создать не наследника, а базовый класс. И ошибка вам показывает, где именно. Вслепую вам больше никто ничего не подскажет.

Comment: Покажите ваш код (ту строчку, которая не компилируется).